# Assersion error using f_printf of fatfs, but f_write works fine

Tags: c, stm32, fatfs

I have a small piece of code that opens a file, reads a single number, adds one and writes it back to the file.
It works fine when I use `f_write`, but `f_open` returns `FR_INT_ERR`.
I'm using version R0.12c.
The code that generates error:

```
FIL indexFile;
char chars[10] = {0};
uint16_t indexNumber = 0;
FRESULT fr;
fr = f_open(&indexFile, INDEX_NAME, FA_READ | FA_WRITE | FA_OPEN_EXISTING);
fr = f_read(&indexFile, &chars, 10, &br);
indexNumber = atoi(chars);
fr = f_lseek(&indexFile, 0);
fr = f_printf(&indexFile, "%d", indexNumber+1);  // produces assertion error
if (fr != FR_OK) printf("Something went wrong");
```

But if I change `fr = f_printf(&indexFile, "%d", indexNumber+1);` to the following, it does not complain:

```
char stringBuffer[5];
sprintf(stringBuffer, "%d", indexNumber+1);
UINT bw;
fr = f_write(&indexFile, stringBuffer, strlen(stringBuffer), &bw);
if (fr != FR_OK || strlen(stringBuffer) != bw) printf("something went wrong");
```

Although I can keep using the second approach but I'm the type of person who needs to understand what is wrong.

BTW: I'm using STM32

Comment: From [f_printf](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/doc/printf.html): `When the string was written successfuly, it returns number of character encoding units written to the file. When the function failed due to disk full or any error, an EOF (-1) will be returned.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that `f_write` does indeed return an `FRESULT` but that `f_printf` will return an `int` indicating the number of characters written. Therefore, checking for `F_OK` as a return does not make sense. You need to instead assert based on the input format string,

Edit: as per @KamilCuk comment, EOF (-1) will be returned on failure, so test for that.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. It's clearly mentioned in the docs, don't know why I was checking for `FRESULT`.